# How can i change c# codes with my words

Tags: c#

I want to change the c# codes to my codes like this :

```
Csl.WL("Hello, World");
```

which means:

```
Console.Wrileline("Hello, World");
```

So, please is there is any way to figure this out?

Comment: While this might seem like it could save you time, it's not exactly something you should do in practice.

Comment: This is probably the worst thing you could do. How do you expect to communicate with anyone?

Comment: Are you tweeting this code?

Comment: Would be good for http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Man, don't do that...

Answer (score 10):

This is a terrible idea. However, you could do it like this:

```
public static class Csl {
    public static void WL(string str) {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
    // repeat for every other method you want to rename
}
```

Again...don't do this. Grab a copy of Visual Studio and take advantage of its autocompletion. The ReSharper extension will make this even easier.

Comment: ReSharper usually isn't an option for someone beginning to code, it does not work in VS Express.

Comment: Here's a gun. I've loaded it for you. Please don't pull the trigger :-)

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge: As long as it isn't pointed at me, I don't care what he does with it ;)

Answer (score 5):

There's even a macro (snippet) in Visual Studio.  Just type `cw`, hit TAB 2 times and it will change to `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: This is actually called a "snippet" but it is an excellent shortcut!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that? If you don't want to write long codes in VS 2010/2012/2013 etc. just use autocomplete function. If it is so exhausting for you just write your target code's Upper Cases. For example;

Don't write;

```
Console.WriteLine("...");
```

just write;

```
Console.wl
```

and VS will automatically find exact code or codes, which have Upper Case Letters. Then select your code and just click TAB button on your keyboard.