# How to Change C# language

Tags: c#

i'm learning programming on c# in my university country with French language and i wonder
 if i can change word to french to be more easly for me, ex:
From:

```
string name = Console.ReadLine();
if(name=="Aymen")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, Aymen");
}
```

To:

```
chain nom = Console.ReadLine();
Si(nom=="Aymen")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bonjour, Aymen");
}
```

What i did is i change the "string" and "if" with "chain" and "Si".
Thanks

Comment: You can use `using chain = System.String;` but other part seems not possible and not logical.

Comment: Others won't understand your code. Instead, spend more time learning English, which is the lingua franca of software engineering.

Comment: Although technically possible (especially with Roslyn) it is exceptionally hard. Added to the fact that, I know for a fact that even in french firms, they use English based programming languages.

Comment: oh, how badly I want a `Console.ÉcrireLigne` method...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i change c# codes with my words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724036/how-can-i-change-c-sharp-codes-with-my-words)

Answer (score 12):

No, that's not possible (and a bad idea anyway).

---

C# has a clearly designed [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) that defines all language constructs, and such "translations" are not part of it. It would be possible to create a computer language with such a feature, but the impact would be huge:

- the list of [keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx) would increase for each "language"(in your example, `Si` has be a reserverd keyword).
- learning the language would be harder.
- the majority of users of the language would not be able to read your code (just think about the fact that each basic type has multiple names.
- as a professional developer, you would probably still need to learn the english version, and learning the french version first would be wasted time.
- it would be much harder to write a compiler for such a language (harder == needs more time == costs more money), for very little gain.

So I would not be surprised to see a esoteric fun computer language with such a feature; but a production ready mainstream language? No.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the keywords of a language is a wrong way learning the language and learning coding.

Answer (score 1):

The reserved and contextual keywords of C#, and most languages, cannot be changed - the compiler expects them to be pre-defined and unambiguous. No mainstream language allows for this. This covers the `string` and `if` in your example.

The class and member names of the available libraries and frameworks are contained in the libraries themselves. Technically you could replace the libraries with your own (yes, you can write your own System.dll and mscorlib.dll, if you are very, very bored) - but some names are expected and are necessary - for example, you can't replace `Monitor.Enter` or `GetEnumerator)()` / `MoveNext()` / `get_Current` with something different - the compiler will simply break. This covers `Console`, `ReadLine` and `WriteLine` in your example.

However! The fields, variables, types and members *inside your own code* can be anything *reasonable* in unicode. And of course your string literals can contain any unicode you want. So you can have:

```
static class す {
    static void Main() {
        ず();
    }
    static void ず() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is to change the types and the keywords of the programming language, then its structure. Since the compiler expects to work with the standard structure defined by Microsoft, your changes won't work. For this reason, what you're asking isn't possible.

If you want to change the keywords and define a new structure, read few books and learn something about compilers and programming languages. Then, maybe, you'll be able to create your own programming language with a structure defined by yourself.

Everybody, I think, wants to change the structure of a programming language according to the spoken language, in order to read it in an easier way. I thought many times something about `Console.LeggiRiga()` (Italian translation for `Console.ReadLine()`), but this would mean that my source code would be readable and understandable only by Italian speakers.

Using English, we're able to understand each other what we're doing with the code, since English ,as @OndrejTucny said, is the lingua franca of software engineering.